# Signalr hub with Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, nunit, signalr.client

I am using nUnit Test and Signalr with .net framework 4.5 and I get error like :

> *System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request.
>         ----> System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server
>         ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6790*

Actually I need to test when **hub.GetCallControlData();** being called then it should be invoked **SetServer**  method

code :

```
[HubName("SignalRHub")]
public class SignalRHub1 : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public void GetCallControlData()
    {
        Clients.Caller.SetServer("Server");
    }
}
```

Test

```
[TestFixture]
public class SignalrHubTest1
{
    public interface IClientContract
    {

        void SetServer(string s);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task MockSingalrHub()
    {
        var url = "http://localhost:6790";
        var connectionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var mockRequest = new Mock<IRequest>();
        var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
        var mockProxy = new Mock<IHubProxy>();
        var _connection = new HubConnection(url);
        var clientContract = new Mock<IClientContract>();

        var mockHeaders = new Mock<INameValueCollection>();
        mockHeaders.Setup(h => h["host"]).Returns(url); 

        mockRequest.Setup(r => r.Headers).Returns(mockHeaders.Object);
        clientContract.Setup(_ => _.SetServer(It.IsAny<string>()));


        mockClients.Setup(m => m.Caller).Returns(clientContract.Object);

        var hub = new SignalRHub1()
        {

            Clients = mockClients.Object,
            Context = new HubCallerContext(mockRequest.Object, connectionId)
        };


        var _hub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("SignalRHub");
        mockProxy.Setup(x => x.Subscribe(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new Subscription());
        _hub.On<string>("SetServer", x => SetServer(x));

       await hub.OnConnected();
        hub.GetCallControlData();
        clientContract.VerifyAll();
        await _connection.Start();
    }
    internal void SetServer(string s)
    {
      //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: This would be an integration test. To this to be a unit test, you need to mock the hub responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unit tests are meant to be isolated. There is no need to connect to an actual server in order to verify expected behavior.

Given the shown `Hub`,

```
[HubName("SignalRHub")]
public class SignalRHub1 : Hub {

    public void GetCallControlData() {
        Clients.Caller.SetServer("Server");
    }
}
```

the following isolated unit test behaves as expected and verifies that the `SetServer("Server")` is invoked.

```
[TestClass]
public class SignalrHub1Tests {
    public interface IClientContract {
        void SetServer(string s);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCallControlData_Should_SetServer() {
        //Arrange
        var contract = new Mock<IClientContract>();
        contract.Setup(_ => _.SetServer(It.IsAny<string>()));

        var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
        mockClients.Setup(_ => _.Caller).Returns(contract.Object);

        var hub = new SignalRHub1() {
            Clients = mockClients.Object
        };

        //Act
        hub.GetCallControlData();

        //Assert
        contract.Verify(_ => _.SetServer("Server"));
    }
}
```